# Update Customer - Intuit Anywhere

Tags: quickbooks

We are trying to add write back feature in our application.
We are using Java SDK. We trying two ways to update an existing customer

Method 1

1. Retrieve the customer object using customerQuery
2. Use th same customer object to update
3. Successfully updated.

Method 2

1. Create new customer object
2. set Id using SetId() method for the newly created object
3. update customer
4. Getting following exception

-2001Error Detail :: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'MiddleName'. One of '{"http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":SyncToken, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":MetaData, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":ExternalKey, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":Synchronized, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":AlternateId, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":CustomField, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":Draft, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":ObjectState, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":PartyReferenceId, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":TypeOf}' is expected.
com.intuit.ds.qb.IDSException: Error (-2001): cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'MiddleName'. One of '{"http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":SyncToken, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":MetaData, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":ExternalKey, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":Synchronized, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":AlternateId, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":CustomField, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":Draft, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":ObjectState, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":PartyReferenceId, "http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2":TypeOf}' is expected.

Method 1 is working perfectly. But have i susses with method 2.
Is the first method is correct ?
What is the problem with second method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Method 2
>
> Create new customer object set Id using SetId() method for the newly
>   created object update customer Getting following exception

This ^^^ won't work because you aren't providing the SyncToken value then.

Look at the [docs](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0100_Calling_Data_Services/0020_Updating_an_Object) and look at the [update a QuickBooks customer examples](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/IDS_XML_for_Updating_a_Customer), paying special attention to that SyncToken tag that always shows up.

The *latest* SyncToken tag must ALWAYS be provided whenever you do an update/mod operation with QuickBooks. That means that to update a customer *you must always do a query first to grab the latest SyncToken value*, set the SyncToken in your mod/update request, and then send the request.

More information about SyncTokens on our [QuickBooks integration wiki](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/What_is_a_SyncToken).